In Antd v5, how to use custom css variables in ConfigProvider
I posted a issue here, but no response
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/49041
so the issue is I defined some color tokens under :root, but its so confusing that, it works at some level of the ConfigProvider tokens, so what the reason? and how I can use it correctly
I could use css tokens in theme

Why don't you just set all the colors in ConfigProvider theme.token instead of setting it in variable css?

@MuhammadNoumanRafique because it so messy to manage these color codes, color token is easy to read and share
